# Workaround for failing DEL not setting errorlevel

Tags: cmd

I am disappointed to see

```
S:\!DJ DAP>del nofile || pause
Could Not Find S:\!DJ DAP\nofile
S:\!DJ DAP>
```

i.e. no pause. Cause is revealed by:

```
S:\!DJ DAP>echo Exit Code is %errorlevel%
Exit Code is 0
```

What's the most direct workaround?

PS Though official DEL docs don't say errorlevel should be set upon error, this

```
S:\!DJ DAP>del
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

S:\!DJ DAP>echo Exit Code is %errorlevel%
Exit Code is 1
```

and this https://ss64.com/nt/del.html suggest it should. By no stretch is missing target file not an error!

Comment: thegards offers the correct answer. You could work around `del`'s behavior by testing the file exists before attempting to delete it.

Comment: To play Devil's advocate: why _should_ `del` return an error if the file you asked it to delete isn't there? You have requested a state where the file does not exist. If that state _already exists_, it just means `del` has less work to do to achieve your desired state.

Comment: "You have requested a state where the file does not exist" Incorrect. As the docs says, I have requested to delete a given file. If that operation fails due to the file being absent e.g. due to incorrect name, then that's an error, and I expect the command to return an error code.